# angular material design in visual studio md html tags: cannot resolve tag "md-toolbar"

Tags: html, visual-studio, angular-material

Maybe I am the only one who works with MD in VS, but it would be nice if there was a way of making studio recognize these tags without manually adding them into the VS's "formatting and validation" config, one at a time

Comment: There are couple of other people as well. Wondering why? :-)